# SwiftUI: Prevent Image() from expanding view rect outside of screen bounds

Tags: swift, swiftui

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI view where an image should expand the entire screen (`edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`), and then overlay a view on top of that, that also fills the entire screen, but respects the safe area.

#### What I've tried

This is my code, which comes close:

```
struct Overlay: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        EmptyView()
        Spacer()
        Text("My top/right aligned view.")
          .padding()
          .background(Color.red)
      }
      Spacer()
      HStack {
        Text("My bottom view")
          .padding()
          .background(Color.pink)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Overlay_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ZStack {
      Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "background")!)
        .resizable()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
      Overlay()
    }
  }
}
```

#### The issue and tested solutions

The issue is that the image is not clipped it looks like, so it expands the parent view to a width larger than the screen width, which then makes the top right aligned red text box float off screen (see image).

[image]

I tried using `.clipped()` in various places, with no luck. I would preferably avoid using `GeometryReader` if possible.

#### Q: How can I make the image view only fill the screen?

Comment: I've added a non-GeometryReader [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596283/14351818)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to limit the frame size of the out-of-bounds *Image* before it is being picked up by the *ZStack* to avoid the *ZStack* to grow and so the *Overlay* to go out of position.

**edit:** aheze shows with his answer a way around using `GeometryReader` by putting the `Image` into the background of `Overlay()` with `.background(Image()..)`. This avoids the usage of `ZStack` and `GeometryReader` completely and is possibly a cleaner solution.

#### Based on parent view size

```
struct IgnoringEdgeInsetsView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Image("smile")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width,
                           maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
            }
            Overlay()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Based on screen size

```
struct IgnoringEdgeInsetsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("smile-photo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 
                       maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            Overlay()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Great, thank you! I didn't think of `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`, my mind automatically went for `GeometryReader`. Also didn't know about the `maxWidth`/`maxHeight`, which makes more sense than setting a fixed width. :)

Comment: I added a `GeometryReader` example :-)

Comment: why GeometryReader isn't integrated in stacks automatically? would be cleaner.

Comment: @fullmoon Maybe for performance reasons? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @eivindml UIScreen.main.bounds will cause an issue when device rotates.

Answer (score 19):

#### No need to mess with GeometryReader!

Instead, you can prevent the image from overflowing by using the [`.background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)) modifier.

**Note:** The view on top (`OverlayView`) must fill the screen for `.ignoresSafeArea` to work. Here, the spacers make it fill the screen, but it's good practice to use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` anyway.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        OverlayView()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background { /// here!
                Image("City")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
    }
}

struct OverlayView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("My top/right aligned view.")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("My bottom view")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.pink)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image in background, content on top does not overflow]

Comment: This is definitely a better generalized and more idiomatic solution for constraining view sizes than @Fabian's answer. For other readers: both `background()` and `overlay()` will constrain the view you give it to the receiving view's bounds.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the complete code here; `Overlay()` is not defined in the sample code.

Comment: This is correct. GeometryReader will create new image instances when view size is changed.

Comment: Use this example on SecondScreen with a landscaped image. While moving back to FirstScreen, issues remain if the boundary is not handled.