# SwiftUI how to fit ZStackView to device view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm following a tutorial where we are building a slotmachine. However the way it fits on the tutorial as opposed to mine is not the same. The stackviews on my device breach all the devices edges and I can't get it to look alike. All the spacing on the stack views are set to 0. The only problem I would think could disrupt would be the gradient background made to ignore all the edges.

Below is my screen vs the instructors screen.

[image: This is my screen]

and here is the one from the tutorial

[image]

There are also some fixed frame positions we've set. However those are only for the stackviews of the images above. Any help and guide in the right direction is appreciated

Code: Below

```
ZStack {
            // MARK: BACKGROUND
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("ColorPink"), Color("ColorPurple")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            //MARK: INTERFACE
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                
                
                //MARK: - HEADER
                
                LogoView()
                
                Spacer()
                
                // MARK: SCORE
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Your\nCoins".uppercased())
                            .scoreLabelStyle()
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            
                        Text("100")
                            .scoreNumberStyle()
                            .modifier(ScoreNumberModifier())
                    }
                    .modifier(ScoreContainerModifier())
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("200")
                            .scoreNumberStyle()
                            .modifier(ScoreNumberModifier())
                        
                        Text("High\nScore".uppercased())
                            .scoreLabelStyle()
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            
                    }
                    .modifier(ScoreContainerModifier())
                    
                    
                }
               
                // MARK: - SLOT MACHINE
                
            VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                    // MARK - REEL #1
                    ZStack {
                        ReelView()
                        Image("gfx-bell")
                            .resizable()
                            .modifier(ImageModifier())
                    }
                  
                HStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 0){
                    // MARK - REEL #2
                    ZStack {
                        ReelView()
                        Image("gfx-seven")
                            .resizable()
                            .modifier(ImageModifier())
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                
                    // MARK - REEL #3
                    ZStack {
                        ReelView()
                        Image("gfx-cherry")
                            .resizable()
                            .modifier(ImageModifier())
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: 500)
                    // MARK - SPIN BUTTON
                Button(action: {
                    print("Spin the reels")
                }) {
                    Image("gfx-spin")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .modifier(ImageModifier())
                }
                    // Slot Machine
                }
                .layoutPriority(2)
```

Comment: This might help for the image overflowing - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596283/14351818

Comment: Also can you post your code?

Comment: It looks like you hardcoded your image sizes, remove those all and it will fit automatically.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for this, ended up having contradictory constraints. Its now working as it should.