# Why is my SF Symbol going of the screen in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Here see how the symbol box is off the page:

[image]

My code:

```swift
ZStack {
    Image("night").ignoresSafeArea()
    
    VStack {
        
        Spacer().frame(height: 260)
        
        Text("Melbourne, Victoria")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        
        Spacer().frame(height: 25)
        
        Image(systemName: "moon.fill")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.system(size: 60))
        
        
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text("Today")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        
        Text("34°C")
            .font(.title3)
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        
        Spacer().frame(height: 780)
        
        HStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

So as you can see I put the SF symbol but on the preview it goes off the page. Any way to fix it?

Comment: You’re explicitly setting the height of your spacer to 780. Remove the frame modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 problems that are producing this weird result:

1. Your `Image("night")` is a huge image and overflows out of the screen. To prevent this, try setting it as the `VStack`'s background instead. Here's a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57593552/14351818).
2. You have lots of `Spacer`s, including a `Spacer().frame(height: 780)` as [@jnpdx commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278479/why-is-my-sf-symbol-going-of-the-screen-in-xcode#comment122447973_69278479). Remove it.
   Usually, when you're adding a `.frame` to a `Spacer`, you want [`padding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)) instead. I've replaced the various `Spacer().frame(height: ...)`s with `padding`s below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Melbourne, Victoria")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 25)
            
            Image(systemName: "moon.fill")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
            
            
            Text("Today")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            Text("34°C")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 60))
            }
            
        }
        .background(
            Image("night")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image and icon both do not overflow]

Comment: @AirWalks great, can you click the green checkmark to accept the answer if it worked?